# Is it ok to ask questions about a game featuring lightly clothed characters on Arqade?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I recently discovered a new versus fighting game.  While it features lightly clothed characters (girls, actually), I'd have some questions to ask about it, like

- how to make it work properly on a recent Windows (the game dates back to 2002)
- is it controler ready
- how to make special attacks
- etc

So before getting worried by the Arqade community for an honest mistake, I prefere to ask it on meta: is it ok to ask about that kind of game around here?

Comment: Sorry, gotta ban you from meta for asking whether or not you'll get banned for asking about the game.

Comment: How is this game any more off limits than the dead or alive series?

Comment: I was precisely thinking about DoA while writing this.  But didn't find any DoA related question on Arqade.  Also, DoA doesn't exactly assume its vulgarity as well as BKB (almost, but not exactly)

Comment: DoA is a strong fighting game, regardless of it's character design.

Comment: And pretty much admitting you're using a pirated copy, makes it off-topic doesn't it?

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Answer (score 12):

It very much depends on what you ask and how. You could argue that Gnome got banned from chat for less than the picture shown before you click play on that video. You could argue that as soon as we remained very much professional, we could argue about stun frames and damage numbers of kicks to the groin just fine.

I don't have a definitive answer for you beyond what the content policy says:

> Sexually Explicit Material. Accounts that use Stack Exchange to post sexually explicit or pornographic material, or links to it, will be suspended.

To be on the safe side of things:

- Avoid screenshots
- Avoid describing the "special attacks"
- Keep it PG-13
- Be aware at all times that this game is *highly likely to be exceedingly bad* given [the gameplay shown in the original video looks dreadful](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MqDWL0MgAtc&t=17m30s), so covering it is not exactly a priority.
- Be prepared to the possibility that your question (or answer) could cost you 100 reputation + downvotes if 5 people believe it's over the line.

Comment: Oh god, this is not encouraging at all.

Comment: @Anto really? Seems like most necessary questions could quite easily be limited to text only with no discussion of naughty bits...

Comment: Yeah no, I know, but from what @badp says (his last point), it's still pretty "dangerous" to ask about that game (while it's not especially grosser than others versus fighting games featuring almost naked girls).  Even this meta question got downvoted, not sure why, but possibly because it terribly hurted some sensible minds.

Comment: @badp wouldn't it take six people believing it's over the line (and thus flagging offensive), or am I misremembering?

Comment: @Anto I for one downvoted because the game looks absolutely abysmal.

Comment: In what way does it make the question bad ?  Since when the quality of the game is revelant about the quality of the question ? 
Should I downvote all PHP questions on Stackoverflow because I think it's a horrible language (wouldn't ever do that, just asking) ? Moreover the question isn't especially about BKB, it was more an example and a way to give context.

Comment: @Anto downvotes on meta can mean disagreement, it's kind of a quick "no" answer

Comment: @jmfsg oh, ok, I had no idea of that.  Pretty misleading.

Comment: @Badp I visited your 'exceedingly bad' link, and during the last 45 seconds, when the Maria 64 music started playing, I was slapped in the face with so much nostalgia its disgusting.

Comment: *[cleared a few comments about PHP and voting thereof that were getting off-topic]*

Comment: that's so typical American: As long as blood and gore is featured it is perfectly fine, but with light clothed characters it is a no-go. Also 'keep it PG-13' isn't any guideline at all, because a lot of ppl here live in countries which havn't such a rating scheme and also it's OK to discuss other 'not PG-13'-features as long as they are about violence, gambling etc...

Comment: @Andalur I'm not American.

Comment: @badp But you refer to an american rating system.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't post any screenshots you should be good.  I think.